# useState does not support a second callBack, what could be the easy fix?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    let pageId =
      props.initialState.content[props.location.pathname.replace(/\/+?$/, "/")]
        .Id;

    if (props.initialState.currentContent.Url !== props.location.
      setCurrentContent({ currentContent: { Name: "", Content: "" } }, () => {
        fetch(`/umbraco/surface/rendercontent/byid/${pageId}`, {
          credentials: "same-origin"
        })
          .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
              return response.json();
            }
            return Promise.reject(response);
          })
          .then(result => {
            setCurrentContent({
              currentContent: { Name: result.Name, Content: result.Content }
            });
          });
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

I have tried things like `useCallback`/`useMemo` but yet no luck, I'm sure this is a simple fix but I must be missing the bigger picture, thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the desired outcome here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is write an effect that checks if the currentContent state is changed and empty and takes the necessary action. You would however need to ignore the initial render. Also unline setState in class components you don't pass on the state value as object instead just pass the updated state

```
const ContentPage = props => {
   const [currentContent, setCurrentContent] = useState({
    Name: props.initialState.currentContent.Name,
    Content: props.initialState.currentContent.Content
   });

  const initialRender = useRef(true);

   useEffect(() => {
     let pageId =
       props.initialState.content[props.location.pathname.replace(/\/+?$/, 
     "/")]
         .Id;
     if (
       initialRender.current &&
       currentContent.Name == "" &&
       currentContent.Content == ""
     ) {
       initialRender.current = false;
       fetch(`/umbraco/surface/rendercontent/byid/${pageId}`, {
         credentials: "same-origin"
       })
         .then(response => {
           if (response.ok) {
             return response.json();
           }
           return Promise.reject(response);
         })
         .then(result => {
           setCurrentContent({ Name: result.Name, Content: result.Content });
         });
     }
   }, [currentContent]);

   useEffect(() => {
     if (props.initialState.currentContent.Url !== props.location) {
       setCurrentContent({ Name: "", Content: "" });
     }
   }, []);
   ...
 };


 export default ContentPage;
```

Comment: This for some reason is not working, I can not see the content, by the looks of it, it is setting the content to " " and not filling it after.

Comment: @Andrew, It seems that currentContent is not the name of state that is returned from useState instead you must add state.currentContent within useEffect deps array

Comment: Got this -  ReferenceError: state is not defined, sorry for the bothers but I just cant figure it out, might have to set it back to the class component... I have the class component working if you want to see it?

Comment: @Andrew, state here was just an example. whatever you call the state returned by `useState` you would use that in place of `state`

Comment: @Shaubham I have put currentContent which is the state, and the data still disapears... Not sure why, this is the code working with class component: https://gist.github.com/ElAndy94/701b990fe843f72a2c2a09d3017d9e7d and then this is the code without the class component not working: https://gist.github.com/ElAndy94/c827e4698454e1a69f4fdcb527e7a880

Comment: @Andrew Updated my answer. There was a problem in how you were setting state, Notice: `setCurrentContent({ Name: result.Name, Content: result.Content });`

Comment: I have checked it all and still the content is there for a split second upon refresh and then its gone.

Comment: Did you change `setCurrentContent({ Name: "", Content: "" });` too

Comment: Yeah I did but also, have you noticed that `pageId` is not being read?

Comment: My Mistake, initialRender was not being used currently. Updated the solution. Also where is `pageId` being used from

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192754/discussion-between-andrew-and-shubham-khatri).